# Как получить конкретные комментарии?

Tags: django

Мне нужно во вьюхе получить только те комментарии, которые пренадлежат конкретной книге.

**models.py**

```
Model Book
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Название')

Model Comment
class Comment(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, related_name='+')
```

**views.py**

```
class ViewBook(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'app/onebook.html'
    context_object_name = 'book'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'book_id'
 
     def get_queryset(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(????)

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filer(?????)
        return context
```

Comment: Вам по идее нужно отобразить все так что `objects.all()`, Имхо я бы добавил в модели поле active для включения отключения комментов, и тогда objects.filer(active=True)

Comment: @Kers если obj.all(), то для каждой книги будут все комментарии из бд, а не конкретные комментарии к конкретной книге

Comment: Странно у меня аналогичный код работает и отображает с привязкой к посту(книги). P.S. Контекст инициализирован по другому. `context = super(Book, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я уже решил вот таким способом. 
name = Book.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['book_id'])[0]
Comment.objects.filter(book__title=name)

Answer (score 0):

Сначала получаем конкретную книгу. Потом передаем в фильтр эту книгу. Через двойное подчеркивание можно обратиться к конкретному полю из модели.

```
name = Book.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['book_id'])[0] 
Comment.objects.filter(book__title=name)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]